# How to format a number with an expression in SSRS based on a value?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2012

I have fields called `price` and `minIncrement` in my DataSet for my SSRS 2012 report. I want to format the `price` using an expression based on the `minIncrement` field. For example if the `price` is `94.95000` and the `minIncrement` is `0.01`, then I want the `price` displayed on the report as `94.95`. If the `price` is `12345.000000` and the `minIncrement` is `1`, then display the `price` as `12345`.

Is there a way to do that? Possible `minIncrement` values are

```
0.000100
0.010000
0.100000
0.250000
1.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an expression, something like:

```
=Format(
    Fields!Price.Value, 
    Switch(
        Fields!MinIncrement.Value = 0.000100, "0.0000",
        Fields!MinIncrement.Value = 0.010000, "0.00",
        Fields!MinIncrement.Value = 0.100000, "0.0"
    )
)
```

Just expand the `Switch` statement with the other possible values for MinIncrement.